# Iterate through two array at the same time in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, iteration

I have two array and I want to display them in a 
conversation manner using ng-repeat

assume two array are defined like this

```js
messages_send = ["hi","good, How about you?","cool","LOL","NFW"]   
messages_received = ["hey, How are you?","good, Thanks","hmmm","asdfsda"]
```

```
<ul>
    <span ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">
        <li>
            messages_send[i]
        </li>
        <li>
            messages_received[i]
        </li>
    </span>
</ul>
```

I did it that way and it wroked only problem is it messed up the conversation layout I had. Is there another way to do this I mean iterating through two arrays using ng-reapet without messing up the layout ?

Thanks

Comment: why not map them to one array?

Answer (score 1):

You could do some variation of this but you'll need to error check the array to make sure it has the same number of elements.  I'm just using an `ng-show` for that error check but something like this:

```
<ul>
    <span ng-repeat="msg in messages_send track by $index>
        <li>
            {{msg}}
        </li>
        <li> 
          <span ng-show='messages_received.length>=$index'>
            {{messages_received[$index]}}
          </span>
        </li>
    </span>
</ul>
```